# Is This A ... Riddle?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Take the first 3 letters and you can find this on your keyboard

Take the first 5 letters and it means to change something

Take the last 6 letters and it is still a word

What is the word?

Extra Hint :

> It is an adjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> alternative
>  alt is a key on the keyboard
>  alter means to change
>  last 6 letters make the word 'native'
>  And alternative is an adjective

Comment: Hi @KevinL, and welcome to PSE! Your puzzle is a bit broad in that there are several words that fit all the clues. Our convention is that any answer that fits about as well as the intended answer is "correct", even if it wasn't the answer that the asker intended. If you want to make the answer unique (that often makes a puzzle better), the simplest way to rule out the "alternate" answers is, of course, adding more clues. Nice to have you here, and happy puzzling!

Comment: @nikki Correct! Did the hint make the answer too obvious?

Comment: @Bass Noted. Will do so in future questions.

Comment: I actually think the hint helped to narrow down the candidate answers. Without it, there would probably have been many answers like Bass mentioned. Although, I do think the first line made it a little simpler to guess, the one about the key on the keyboard. I would have found it a little more difficult with just the 2nd and 3rd lines and the hint.
But good riddle, and welcome to PSE! :)